# Can anyone please tell me what is "Evaluation of Proofs" in Mathematics?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

[image: Can anyone please tell me what is "Evaluation of Proofs" in Mathematics ?]

I have been told to evaluate the proof of this proposition. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I think you have to check the veracity of the "proof".

Comment: read the proof and determine whether it is a valid proof for the proposition (e.g., is the statement proved the same as the proposition?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluating the proof means determining whether it is valid.

The **Proof** shows that, if $m$ or $n$ is even, then $mn$ is even.

The **Proposition** states the converse:  if $mn$ is even, then $m$ or $n$ is even.

In general, the truth of a statement says nothing about the truth of its converse,

so I find this proof lacking.

Answer (score 0):

If mn = 2K, where K is an integer, then observe that, 2 divides the RHS, so it has to divide the LHS as well... In that case, 2 divides either m or n, making one of them even. If it doesn't divide either, notice that it wouldn't divide mn, thus contradicitng it being even...